# Website video feed with a computer's desktop

Tags: php, video, streaming, desktop

I'm building a website that needs in an area a video feed with a computer desktop.

What I am looking is a software that broadcasts windows desktop and i really can't find any. I run into Livestream Procaster and Ustream Producers but that is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Ustream](http://www.ustream.tv) to broadcast the video feed from your desktop. Ustream offers an embed code, which you can integrate on your website.

Comment: The OP specifically mentions having found Ustream and not being interests.